# Can a LocalBroadcastManager send Intent to global BroadcastReceivers in the same App?

Tags: broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, localbroadcastmanager

Can a LocalBroadcastManager send an Intent to a globally registered BroadcastReceiver if it resides in the same App? Or do I have to use context.sendBroadcast() for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `LocalBroadcastManager` cannot send Intent to global `BroadcastReceivers`.

**Explanation:**
`LocalBroadcastManager` has a private HashMap, in which it maps `BroadcastReceiver` to `ArrayList<IntentFilter>`, when [registerReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html#registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter)) method is called explicitly using any context within application. It does not hold any record of global `BroadcastReceivers` declared in `AndroidManifest.xml`. So, `LocalBroadcastManager` won't send Intent to global `BroadcastReceivers`.

See the below screenshot captured while I debugged `LocalBroadcastReceiver` from my application which has three `BroadcastReceivers` declared globally in `AndroidManifest.xml`

[image]